# How to prevent directory from being deleted by user?

Tags: command-line, permissions, chmod, rm

Suppose a directory `dir1` is created by `sudo` on Desktop.

```
sudo mkdir dir1
```

Then I applied `chown` and `chmod` as following:

```
sudo chown root:root dir1
sudo chmod go-rwx dir1
```

Now `dir1` is only accessible with owner `root`.

```
$ ls -ld dir1
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Jul 29 19:21 dir1
```

---

If user (`$USER` = `pandya`) try to delete `dir1` with **GUI nautilus (without `sudo`)**, then he can't **which is ok**.

[image]

**But if tried to remove with terminal then he can which is not ok:-**

- **`rm -r` (without `sudo`):**

  ```
   $ rm -r dir1
   rm: descend into write-protected directory ‘dir1’? Y
   rm: remove write-protected directory ‘dir1’? Y
   $
  ```
- **And more easily with `rmdir` ! (without sudo):**

  ```
  $ rmdir dir1
  $
  ```

---

**Thus, How to prevent `dir1` to be delete with user than not `sudo`?**

[optional]
My ultimate aim is: Only owner can delete directory, group and other only can read/execute.

Comment: You need to fix this one directory higher.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What said [Class Stacker](https://askubuntu.com/users/308343/class-stacker) in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/504153/147044) is correct, but it didn't solved your problem. To prevent a directory from being deleted by the user which owns all rights to the parent directory (`/home/pandya` in your case) you have to use the `chattr` command.

Here is an example:

```
$ sudo mkdir dir1
$ sudo chattr +i dir1
$ rmdir dir1
rmdir: failed to remove ‘dir1’: Operation not permitted
$ rm -r dir1
rm: remove write-protected directory ‘dir1’? y
rm: cannot remove ‘dir1’: Operation not permitted
$ chattr -i dir1
chattr: Permission denied while setting flags on dir1
```

And in Nautilus:

[image]

Please read `man chattr` for more info.

Comment: I have only knowledge about `chown` and `chmod`. Now Can you help me difference between mode (by `chmod`) and attribute (by `chattr`)? or it is more suitable that I **ask** another **question** for it which i am thinking?

Comment: @Pandya `chmod - change file mode bits` and `chattr - change file attributes`. Just read the manual page of each command and probably you will understand what each one does.

Comment: Good explanation on this `immutable flag` [can be found here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chattr)

Comment: However, by rendering a directory immutable one cannot create, edit or delete any subdirectories or files within this immutable directory.

Comment: When a directory is `immutable` can't we add files therein?

Comment: you have also `undeletable` flag

Answer (score 3):

Actually, directories are special files.

In a directory `/home/user`, the right of creating or removing entires (such as files or directories) is determined by the rights of `/home/user` itself, not by the rights of the entries.

In your case, it would be best to provide a subdirectory, such as `/home/user/fixed`, and set the rights of that to `r-x`. Then, the user will be unable to create or delete files or directories in there. He may still be able to edit, descent, etc based on the rights of the individual files and directories inside `/home/user/fixed`.